# Scala application compiles error in IDEA due to the connection refuse

Tags: scala, sockets, intellij-idea

I'm trying to compile the scala application under IDEA, the scala compile server seems work well, but I got the following error every time I ran the scala application (script runs well).

> Information:Internal caches are corrupted or have outdated format,
>   forcing project rebuild: Module 'Programming-in-Scala' production:
>   java.net.SocketException: SOCKS: Connection refused

And this is the detailed error message.

> Error:Internal error: (java.net.SocketException) SOCKS: Connection
>   refused java.net.SocketException: SOCKS: Connection refused   at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:563)    at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)  at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:425)   at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:241)   at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$class.send(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:24)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteServer.send(RemoteServer.scala:12)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteServer.compile(RemoteServer.scala:17)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder$$anonfun$compile$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ScalaBuilder.scala:47)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder$$anonfun$compile$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ScalaBuilder.scala:41)
>     at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.map(Either.scala:535)  at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder$$anonfun$compile$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ScalaBuilder.scala:41)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder$$anonfun$compile$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ScalaBuilder.scala:40)
>     at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:522)  at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(ScalaBuilder.scala:40)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(ScalaBuilder.scala:39)
>     at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:522)  at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder$.compile(ScalaBuilder.scala:39)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.IdeaIncrementalBuilder.build(IdeaIncrementalBuilder.scala:63)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1140)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:826)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:894)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:789)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:612)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:352)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:191)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:137)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:289)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:124)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:238)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:41)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I think it maybe the problem of `HTTP Proxy`, so I checked this information in the setting. The default setting is `No proxy`. Actually, I'm confused how to set it if needed.

btw, the version of IntelliJ IDEA is 14.0.2 and the OS is mac os x.

Any other point that I may have a try? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

have met the same problem in this version:

`IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.1
Build #IC-143.382, built on November 10, 2015
JRE: 1.8.0_40-release-b92 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
os x Yosemite 10.10.3`

and solve it by reboot ...